# 16.04.5 AMD/ATI RV 515 gpu overheating

Tags: amd-graphics

I have installed 16.4.5 and it comes with ATI RV 515 driver built in for AMD/ATI RV 515/516,and it causes overheating on videos,random shutdown,flicking,hanging and some other problems.the initial release of 16.04 had an open source gallium 0.4  driver for AMD/ATI RV 515/516 GPUs as built in.how i can install it instead of ATI RV 515 driver.my laptop specs are attached as pic.[image]